# Create ORM object from dict and add to session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a `User` model with attributes `id`, `name`, `email` and a relationship `languages`.
Is it possible to create a `User` instance from existing data that behaves like I would have queried it with `dbsession.query(User).get(42)`?
What I mean in particular is that I want that an access to `user.languages` creates a subquery and populates the attribute.

Here a code example:

I have a class `User`:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    email = Column(String(64))

    languages = relationship('Language', secondary='user_languages')
```

I already have a lot of users stored in my DB.
And I know that I have, for example, this user in my DB:

```
user_dict = {
    'id': 23,
    'name': 'foo',
    'email': 'foo@bar',
}
```

So I have all the attributes but the relations.
Now I want to make a sqlalchemy `User` instance
and kind of register it in sqlalchemy's system
so I can get the `languages` if needed.

```
user = User(**user_dict)

# Now I can access the id, name email attributes
assert user.id == 23

# but since sqlalchemy thinks it's a new model it doesn't
# lazy load any relationships
assert len(user.languages) == 0
# I want here that the languages for the user with id 23 appear

# So I want that `user` is the same as when I would have done
user_from_db =  DBSession.query(User).get(23)
assert user == user_from_db
```

The use-case is that I have a big model with lots of complex
relationships but 90% of the time I don't need the data from those.
So I only want to cache the direct attributes plus what else I need
and then load those from the cache like above and be able to
use the sqlalchemy model like I would have queried it from the db.

Answer (score 0):

From the sqlalchemy mailing list:

```py
# to make it look like it was freshly loaded from the db
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import make_transient_to_detached
make_transient_to_detached(user)
# merge instance in session without emitting sql
user = DBSession.merge(user, load=False)
```

---

*This answer was extracted from the question*