# Using arbitrary sqlalchemy select results (e.g., from a CTE) to create ORM instances

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

When I create an instance of an object (in my example below, a `Company`) I want to automagically create default, related objects.  One way is to use a per-row, after-insert trigger, but I'm trying to avoid that route and use CTEs which are easier to read and maintain.  I have this SQL working (underlying db is PostgreSQL and the only thing you need to know about table `company` is its primary key is: `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` and it has one other required column, `name VARCHAR NOT NULL`):

```sql
with new_company as (
     -- insert my company row, returning the whole row
     insert into company (name)
          values ('Acme, Inc.')
       returning *
),

other_related as (
   -- herein I join to `new_company` and create default related rows
   -- in other tables.  Here we use, effectively, a no-op - what it
   -- actually does is not germane to the issue.
   select id from new_company
)

-- Having created the related rows, we return the row we inserted into
-- table `company`.
select * from new_company;
```

The above works like a charm and with the recently added `Select.add_cte()` (in sqlalchemy 1.4.21) I can write the above with the following python:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

from myapp.models import Company

new_company = (
   sa.insert(Company)
   .values(name='Acme, Inc.')
   .returning(Company)
   .cte(name='new_company')
)
other_related = (
   sa.select(sa.text('new_company.id'))
   .select_from(new_company)
   .cte('other_related')
)
fetch_company = (
   sa.select(sa.text('* from new_company'))
   .add_cte(other_related)
)
print(fetch_company)
```

And the output is:

```
WITH new_company AS
(INSERT INTO company (name) VALUES (:param_1) RETURNING company.id, company.name),
other_related AS
(SELECT new_company.id FROM new_company) 
SELECT * from new_company
```

Perfect!  But when I execute the above query I get back a `Row`:

```py
>>> result = session.execute(fetch_company).fetchone()
>>> print(result)
(26, 'Acme, Inc.')
```

I can create an instance with:

```py
>>> result = session.execute(fetch_company).fetchone()
>>> company = Company(**result)
```

But this instance, if added to the session, is in the wrong state, `pending`, and if I flush and/or commit, I get a duplicate key error because the company is already in the database.

If I try using `Company` in the select list, I get a bad query because sqlalchemy automagically sets the from-clause and I cannot figure out how to clear or explicitly set the from-clause to use my CTE.

I'm looking for one of several possible solutions:

- annotate an arbitrary query in some way to say, "build an instance of MyModel, but use *this* table/alias", e.g., `query = sa.select(Company).select_from(new_company.alias('company'), reset=True)`.
- tell a session that an instance is `persistent` regardless of what the session thinks about the instance, e.g., `company = Company(**result); session.add(company, force_state='persistent')`

Obviously I could do another round-trip to the db with a call to `session.merge()` (as discussed in early comments of this question) so the instance ends up in the correct state, but that seems terribly inefficient especially if/when used to return lists of instances.

Comment: You probably want [session.merge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#merging)

Comment: @snakecharmerb, ```session_merge``` doesn't work because 1) in default mode (w/ ```load=True```) sqla will reload the object from the database, which I'm trying to avoid or 2), w/ ```load=False``` throws an InvalidRequestError as it doesn't accept unpersisted objects.  A bit of a Catch-22 issue here.  So the question remains, how do I fetch an object with an arbitrary query (so it's in the session) -or- having an object which I know to be "clean", how do I add it to a session in a persisted state.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70722907/5320906) is what you are looking for?